# Is there a way to add custom reporter option in jest when running programmatically?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jestjs, automated-tests

I'm building a tool in which i have to run the test cases written in jest programmatically, and i want to generate report using mochawesome.
Is there a way to add it?
For example, when we run MOCHA  programmatically we make a constructor of Mocha and we can pass reporter option in it, but Jest is not a constructor apparently...